# when i done one way binding using ng-model the following error occur

Tags: angularjs

when I did data binding using ng-model the following error occurs
here i want to print string contained in the input tag to h2 tag.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-model' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
<div>
    <label>name:
      <input [ERROR ->]ng-model="{{hero.name}}" placeholder="name">
    </label>
</div>"): ng:///AppModule/HeroesComponent.html@16:13
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24312)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:33699)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:33674)
    at eval (compiler.js:33576)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:33576)
    at eval (compiler.js:33446)
    at Object.then (compiler.js:455)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:33445)
```

Comment: Give it a type.

Comment: You don't have to use {{}} for ng-model

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `{{}}`. Do it like this:

```
<input ng-model="hero.name" placeholder="name">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it doesn't edit the value of the hero.name property of an object.I want to change a value of hero.name by input tags value.

Comment: You should also put the variable on the scope if you didn't do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />
```

#### UPDATE

From the angular docs https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#binding-syntax

`{{expression}}` 
`[target]="expression"`
`bind-target="expression"`

is for One-way. Please follow the docs for more info.

```
<input [name]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />
```

Comment: it works but its two way i don't want to show the value of hero.name into input tag.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to declare a type  for your hero (object). Also you don't have to use `{{}}` for angular directives like `ng-model`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.hero={};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <input type="text" ng-model="hero.name" placeholder="name"> <br>
 <span>The enter value is {{hero.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

quick suggestion

```
<ul ng-for="item of items">
<li>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.something">
</li>
</ul>
```